# Installing PHP Cassandra Driver - XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, cassandra, driver

I am trying to install prebuilt binaries of Cassandra PHP driver on my windows xampp installation.

I downloaded the package from here https://pecl.php.net/package/cassandra.

I did the following;

1. Extracted the package and added `php_cassandra.dll` to `c:\xampp\php\ext\`
2. Added `extension=php_cassandra.dll` in `php.ini` file in `c:\xampp\php\php.ini`
3. Restarted the Apache server

Now if I check with command `php -m`, I can see that the Cassandra module is loaded but I cannot see it in `phpinfo()`.

My doubt is where to place cassandra PHP files which I got from pecl (classes etc.) to this.

Now I am getting the error below;

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cassandra' not found" if I run some php. Same code was working fine with Linux servers.

I understand that I need to add those Cassandra PHP files somewhere.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got compatible version from here:

Datastax Cassandra Drivers: http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/windows/cassandra/v1.3.2/

Things to take care.

- Find PHP Version   : php -i | FINDSTR /C:"PHP Version"
- Find Architecture  : php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Architecture"
- Find Compiler      : php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Compiler"
- Find Thread Safety : php -i | FINDSTR /C:"Thread Safety"

For me it was PHP v7.1, x86, MVC14, Thread Safety Enabled.

So the compatible version is cassandra-php-driver-1.3.2-7.1-ts-vc14-x86.zip

- ts   => Thread Safe
- nts  => Non Thread Safe
- vc14 => MVC14

Now it is working perfectly fine. Just 4 steps required.

1. Download compatible version
2. Unzip and copy php_cassandra.dll to c:/xampp/php/ext/
3. Add "extension=php_cassandra.dll" to php.ini file
4. Restart apache server.